# Unix tar: do not preserve full pathnames

Tags: shell, unix, tar

When I try to compress files and directories with `tar` using absolute paths, the absolute path is preserved in the resulting compressed file. I need to use absolute paths to tell `tar` where the folder I wish to compress is located, but I only want it to compress that folder – not the whole path.

For example, `tar -cvzf test.tar.gz /home/path/test` – where I want to compress the folder `test`. However, what I actually end up compressing is `/home/path/test`. Is there anything that can be done to avoid this? I have tried playing with the -C operand to no avail.

Comment: Is there a programming context to this? If not it probably belongs on Unix.SE rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: true, although this could be relevant in shellscripting, it's not tagged as such..

Comment: I’m using it for a shell script, but I reduced the problem to one outside of context. I may have needed to provide extra detail (aka context) to find a solution, so I posted here. I’ll tag it as such now.

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh - so did you see my answer?

Comment: Yup, was waiting to mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `-C` to specify the directory *from which the files look like you want*, and then *specify the files as seen from that directory*:

```
tar -cvzf test.tar.gz -C /home/path test
```

Comment: This still preserves the directory structure *relative* to the specified root directory, which is not what the question appears to be asking (though is apparently what OP needed), but +1 because that's exactly what I was looking for (and the unilateral-flattening approach in the other answer seems like a bizarre thing to want).

Answer (score 41):

This is ugly... but it works...

I had this same problem but with multiple folders, I just wanted to flat every files out. You can use the option "transform" to pass a sed expression and... it works as expected.

this is the expression:

`'s/.*\///g'`    (delete everything before '/')

This is the final command:

```
tar --transform 's/.*\///g' -zcvf tarballName.tgz */*/*.info
```

Comment: This is the only answer I've seen that *actually* does what I'm looking for.

Comment: Better result for multiple directories can be achieved in combination with http://serverfault.com/a/566345/343194. Something like `find ./commondir -type f | tar --transform 's/.*\///g' -cvzf ./file.tar.gz --files-from=/dev/stdin`. This way empty child directories will be excluded.

Comment: Impressive! Found you from the [Materials Modeling stack exchange](https://materials.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Just a note that `--transform` is specific to GNU tar, e.g. in my version (macOS, based on `bsdtar`) the flag `-s '#.*/##g'` worked (I used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54110172/how-to-escape-chars-in-bsd-tar-path-substitution-option for how to properly escape the `/`).

Answer (score 3):

multi-directory example

tar cvzf my.tar.gz example.zip -C dir1 files_under_dir1 -C dir2 files_under_dir2

the files under dir 1/2 should not have path.

Answer (score 1):

```
find -type f | tar --transform 's/.*\///g' -zcvf comp.tar.gz -T -
```

Where `find -type f` finds all the files in the directory tree and using `tar` with `--transform` compresses them without including the folder structure. This is very useful if you want to compress only the files that are the result of a certain search or the files of a specific type like:

```
find -type f -name "*.txt" | tar --transform 's/.*\///g' -zcvf comp.tar.gz -T -
```

Unlike the other answers, you don't have to include `*/*/*` specifying the depth of the directory. `find` handles that for you.

Answer (score 0):

tar can perform transformations on the filenames on the way in and out of the archive. Consider this example that stores a bunch of files in a flat tarfile:

## in the root ~/ directory

```
find logger -name \*.sh | tar -cvf test.tar -T - --xform='s|^.*/||' --show-transformed
```

The `-T -` option tell tar to read a list of files from stdin, the `--xform='s|^.*/||'` applies the sed expression to all the filenames as after they are read and before they are stored. --show-transformed is just a nicety to show you the file names after they are transformed, the default is to show the names as they are read.
There are no doubt other ways besides using find to specify files to archive. For instance, if you have `dotglob` set in bash, you can use ** patterns to wildcard any number of directories, shortening the previous to this:

```
tar -cvf test.tar --xform='s|^.*/||' --show-transformed logger/**/*.sh
```

You’ll have to judge what is best for your situation given the files you’re after.